# trouble understanding javascript function level scope

Tags: javascript, scope

I have trouble understanding `JavaScript` function level scope, as a `C#` programmer it looks wired to me, I will try to explain it through code:

**CODE#1**

```
//Problem
//if same named variable (as in global scope) is used inside function scope,
//then variable defined inside function will be used,global one will be shadowed
var a = 123;
function func() {
    alert(a); //returns undefined,why not just return 123 ?
    //how come js knew that there is variable 'a' will be defined and used in 
    //this function scope ,js is interpreter based ?
    var a = 1; //a is defined inside function
    alert(a); //returns 1 
}
func();
```

**CODE#2**

```
//when a variable(inside function) not named as same as the global,
//then it can be used inside function,and global variable is not shadowed
var k = 123;
function func2() {
    alert(k); //returns 123 ,why not 'undefined'
    var c = 1;
    alert(c); //returns 1
}
func2();
```

**So my questions are**

1. in *CODE#1* why first time `a` is `undefined`,why not it's just return `123`? And how
   come `js` knew that there is variable 'a' will be defined and used in
   this function scope, `js` is interpreter based?
2. in *CODE#2* why not `k` is 'undefined'?

http://jsfiddle.net/Nu2Vu/

Comment: This is called `hoisting` in `js` http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting.html

Comment: btw hoising is not the same as function level scope. try for example (in firefox) the same, with `let` instead of `var`.it does the same thing, and `let` has block level scope

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## CODE #1

[Hoisting](http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting.html) causes all variable declarations to be brought to the top of the scope, but it leaves the assignment where it is. When there is a reference to a variable JavaScript will first look in the current scope, if it doesn't find the variable it will continue to look up the scope chain until if finds the variable.
This code is interpreted something like this:

```
var a = 123; // global var named a declared, assigned a value
function func() {
  var a; // the declaration of the local var a gets
         // hoisted to the top of the scope, but the
         // assignment is left below, so at the point
         // it is initialized with a value of `undefined`
    alert(a); // looks for a local var named a, finds it but
              // it currently has a value of `undefined`

    a = 1; // now the value is assigned to the local a
    alert(a); // returns 1 
}
func();
```

## CODE #2

This code behaves the way it does because of [closure](http://www.hunlock.com/blogs/Closing_The_Book_On_Javascript_Closures).
A basic definition of closure is that JavaScript functions have access not only to variables defined in their own scope, they can also access variables available to their parent scope.

```
var k = 123; // declares and assigns a value to global k
function func2() {
    alert(k); // looks for a local var named k, doesn't find it,
              // looks in its parent scope (the global scope in
              // this case) finds k, returns its value of 123
    var c = 1;
    alert(c); //returns 1
}
func2();
```

Answer (score 5):

The first code is equal to this:

```
var a = 123;
function func() {
    var a; //Undefined!
    alert(a); 
    a = 1; 
    alert(a); 
}
```

This explains it pretty well:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var

Comment: Just wanted to add that this is called "Variable Hoisting".

Comment: @Ben thanks for introducing me to the term ,I didn't knew this :)